# Typescript/Angular delete/splice object in Array with parameters

Tags: angular, typescript

```
 deleteContact(id: number) {
const index = FORMULARLIST.indexOf({ ...this.formular }, 0);

    if (index > -1) {
      FORMULARLIST.splice(index, 1);


    }
    console.log(FORMULARLIST);
}

<div *ngIf="selectedformular">

    <h2>{{selectedformular.name | uppercase}} Details</h2>
    <div><span>id: </span>{{selectedformular.id}}</div>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input id="name" [(ngModel)]="selectedformular.name" placeholder="name">
        <input id="name" [(ngModel)]="selectedformular.mobileNumber" placeholder="name">
        <input id="name" [(ngModel)]="selectedformular.secondMobileNumber" placeholder="name">
        <input id="name" [(ngModel)]="selectedformular.email" placeholder="name">
        <input id="name" [(ngModel)]="selectedformular.secondEmail" placeholder="name">
        <input id="name" [(ngModel)]="selectedformular.roomNumber" placeholder="name">
        <input id="name" [(ngModel)]="selectedformular.task" placeholder="name">
        <button (click)="deleteContact(selectedformular.id)" class="btn btn- danger">Delete</button>
        <button (click)="saveContact()" class="btn btn-warning">Save</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

**I don't know how to set the parameters so that the selected objects are deleted. It should be possible that only the selected objects are deleted and not always the first or the last object. It should work with parameters**

Comment: Have you tried `const index = FORMULARLIST.indexOf(this.formular, 0);`? If this does not work, please show us the data in question.

Comment: That doesn´t work

Comment: Great job on reading the first half of my comment. Now I wish you the best of luck to decrypt the second half of it for some awesome magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const index = FORMULARLIST.indexOf({ ...this.formular }, 0);
```

That won't work as `{ ...this.formular }` has different object reference.

Try `array.findIndex`

```
deleteContact(id: number) {
    const index = FORMULARLIST.findIndex(pr => pr.id === id);

    if (index > -1) {
        FORMULARLIST.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(FORMULARLIST);
}
```